# My python script (skuk.py) wont build on sublime text 3: File "C:\Users\Jonathan Karlsson\Desktop\skuk.py", line 3, in <module>

Tags: python, selenium, build, module, sublimetext3

I am very new to python scripts and I do not know how to continue with my project on sublime text when this error occurs: File "C:\Users\Jonathan Karlsson\Desktop\skuk.py", line 3, in

I Cannot build on sublime text 3 with my script saved as skuk.py.
This is my sublime text:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts')

#click on item called photo
#driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('sweatshirts').click()
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.